# What is going on with this jquery animate effect?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-animate

I can't get the jQuery animate effect to work.  What is strange is when I add in a .click function it works fine.

Can anyone suggest a solution or work around to get this effect to run on the page load?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var image2_template = $(".image2_template");
    console.log(image2_template.length);
    $(image2_template).effect( "pulsate", 
        {times:5}, 3000 );
});
```

The console returns a value of 1 so .image2_template is an object, I have no idea why the animation won't fire.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "when I add in a .click function"?  How do you add the click function that makes things work?

Comment: @Jacob so if I use this code things work fine.  I'm wondering if it is something with the delay before running the animation. `       $(document).ready(function() {

  $("#text4").click(function(){
     $(".image2_template").effect( "pulsate", 
      {times:5}, 3000 );
  });

  });`

Ok I don't know what I'm doing.  Why didn't that format as code.

Comment: Since Bertrand Marron's jsfiddle works, I'm guessing that the pulsate is happening, but maybe you can't see it happening because things aren't populated in your page right after it's ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably not including jQuery UI.

See http://jsfiddle.net/tusbar/Xgftz/ for a working demo.